# Not able to user select entered text in v-select search

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have custom v-select search in vuetify.
When i enter text in v-text-field and try to select and clear the entered text, its not allowing to select

Below is the code snippet

```
 <template v-slot:prepend-item>
  <div class="fruit-search-box">
    <v-text-field hide-details placeholder="Search" />
  </div>
</template>
```

And below is the playground link to replicate the issue.
[playground link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Resolution: User should be able to enter and select text from the v-text-field.

Comment: First, would the [v-combobox](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpNj0EKgzAQRa8SsnFjdWE3FSsUob1AoQt1ETWVQMyEGMVSevcmUZuu5s+bz8z88o1H1cYXKaN5ojjFmaaD5ETTvBIIZfOBSOmka1oQmjBB1YY2ODTQwLIjhIaJayY59YSThvJzhYvdi/0sZebmaIZlUBDOnqAEI0GIggI4KNKB1VcjWefwjYLqV8edLmS04vGCgYk+qP3iPIv9b3sEh/4zWLJGzOJfdPwJcRIl0QnbejS1/gJ6o1oo) not be a better solution?

Comment: @yoduh for my use case, v-select is better, I think. any issue with using v-select?